# Ошибка в описание метки для условного оператора java

Tags: java

При выполнение поставленной задачи столкнулась  с проблемой правильного написания метки на языке программирования *Java*  и использованием оператора выбора *Switch*.

необходимо обозначить метку таким образом, чтобы при выборе невведенного мною *case* он выдавал ошибку и возвращал в начала программы.

вот листинг моей программы:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int c=0;
        int b=0;
        int[] a;//массив целых чисел
        int m=0;//номер case 
         int n;//количество элементов в массиве
         int i;
         int j;
         int h=10;
            int [] l=new int[10];
l[0]=2;l[1]=4;l[2]=1;l[3]=3;l[4]=12;l[5]=5;l[6]=66;l[7]=14;l[8]=32;l[9]=75;

         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Vvedite nomer case=");
         m = in.nextInt();
         switch(m) {
          case 1:
             System.out.print("Vvedite razmer=");
             n = in.nextInt();
             a = new int[n];
              for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
              {System.out.println("Element=");
                  a[i] = in.nextInt();
                  System.out.println(a[i]);
              } for( i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
                  c=c+a[i];}
              b=c/n;
              System.out.println("srednyaya symma"+b); 
              for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(a[i]<b)
                    {System.out.println("nomer elementa"+i); }
                else;}            
               break;
          case 2:
             System.out.print("Vvedite razmer=");
             n = in.nextInt();
              int[] v=new int[n];//массив целых чисел
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {System.out.println("Element=");
          v[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);      
                System.out.println(v[i]);
            } for( i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
                c=c+v[i];}
            b=c/n;
            System.out.println("symma"+b); 
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(v[i]<b)
                    {System.out.println("g"+i); }
                else;}
               break;
          case 3:
                for( j = 0; j < h; j++){ 
                   c=c+l[j];}
               b=c/h;
               System.out.println("symma"+b); 
               for( i = 0; i < h; i++){
                if(l[i]<b)
                    {System.out.println("g"+i); }
                else;
               }
               break;
         default:      
         }
    }
```

Comment: Небольшая поправка: не "листининг", а "листинг" (listing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы не проверить введённое значение заранее?

```
System.out.print("Vvedite nomer case=");
m = in.nextInt();
while (m < 1 || m > 3)
{
    System.out.print("Неправильно, попробуйте ещё раз: ");
    m = in.nextInt();
} 
switch(m) { ...
```

Comment: Такое в голову не пришло, спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста! В любом случае, валидация введённых данных (то есть, проверка диапазона значений и т. п.) практически всегда нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Просто для информации (вариант @VlaD лучше):

```
MAIN: while (true) {
  switch (in.nextInt()) {
    case 1:
      ...
      break MAIN;
    case 2:
      ...
      break MAIN;
    case 3:
      ...
      break MAIN;
    default:
      System.out.print("Некорректное значение");
  }
}
```